# AMO tag [Do we have one?]

Tags: feature-request, tags

Can we have a tag for questions related to atomic, molecular and optical physics? I'd suggest "AMO-Atomic Molecular and Optical Physics".

On a related note, how many tags we have here match APS subject tags? Perhaps it would be a good idea to include APS subject classification?

I don't know if this specific question has been brought up before. I am just too lazy to look it up. Sorry. :]

Edit: 
APS = American Physical Society. I mean take a look at Phys.Rev.Letters or Europhysics Letters and see how editors categorize subfields. Perhaps we could simply include that categorization as tags?

AMO is pretty much a catch-all phrase for laser cooling, ion trapping, optical lattices, BEC studies, Atom Magnetometry and tons more.

Comment: Hm we have [tag:atomic-physics],[tag:molecules],[tag:molecular-dynamics], and different specific [tag:optics] tags already. Not sure how useful it is to summerize them to a new acronym ... I personally like the specific subfield tags which can be added and combined in a flexible manner better. What does APS mean?

Comment: Edited to reflect your question. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see. If I remember this correctly they had some APS subject tags on TP.SE. I think if the acronyms are official and/or well known enough among the physicists working on these topics, it is not a bad idea.

Comment: v1 was  a bit misleading. APS = My name.